# Infinite page load when submit a form with 2 file input fields

Tags: php, linux

The following code works fine on wamp server, but when I upload it to production server and I submit with 2 small files like 50k, the page loads indefinitely (waited about 10 minutes, timeout on server is 30 sec.), no errors, no nothing.
The server runs on linux php version 5.4.16. I suspect that the problem is a setting in php.ini but can't find it.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES['small_image']);
    var_dump($_FILES['big_image']);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="small_image">
    <input type="file" name="big_image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: The problem was with a third party program (cyberoam) in the network, somehow blocked the upload.

Comment: Do you have any javascript there?

Comment: no javascript, what you see in the code that's it.

Comment: It's quite weird, have you tried without the form? Add a header tag <h1>some text</h1> and comment the form to see if still gets redirected continuously

Comment: I know, it's weird, never see this before on any server. The problem only occurs when I upload 2 files, with just one it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are allowed to submit files. Create a php file with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and check it.
If you are not allowed, create a file called "php.ini" in your web folder with theses lines:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Comment: This is what I got in phpinfo, upload_max_filesize 2M, post_max_size 8M, memory_limit 128M

Comment: Put this in the top of the file, after "<?php"  **error_reporting(E_ALL);**